# System() fails with return value 255/-1 (8 bit representation)

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls, supervisord

I have an executable, which has a few system commands (basically it does copying and running script files).  When I test in standalone (launching the executable myself as with sudo) `system()` is working fine.

Now I integrate my executable with `supervisord`. Functionality of my executable is working fine, but the `system()` command fails with 255 / -1 (8 bit representation).

List of things I checked:

1. The current working directory of the process is correct
2. Supervisord and my process are running as root
3. chown of directory and file are root

Any other suggestions?

Comment: `-1` means the process exited due to a failure, but the failure is application-specific so we have no way of knowing what it means. Why don't you show us your `system()` call? We're not mind-readers.

Comment: system("sudo cp ./Scripts/x.sh /tmp/"); system("sudo chmod +x /tmp/x.sh");system("sudo /tmp/x.sh");

Comment: I felt the problem is outside of code. like cwd, or ownership of process or loc

Comment: Does your sudoers contain a `requiretty` config option?

Comment: any clue ? Am I missing any information here?

Comment: @mohan, well is the `requiretty` set to `on` or `off`. `sudo` will require a terminal if `requiretty` is `on`, so then it won't work in supervisord. A CWD issue is also likely since you're working with relative paths.

Comment: you guys are awesome. When I removed sudo then everything worked fine. Now it is a happy weekend :) thanks

Comment: `system()` returns an `int` result. Describing that result as `256/ -1` is a bit confusing. Just tell us the `int` value as a single number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
system("sudo cp ./Scripts/x.sh /tmp/");
```

sudo is the command to obtain superuser rights. It normally promts you for password (but under some circumstances, it skips it). Maybe it fails if it has no console to prompt you.

Anyway you should NOT do this. You sould just write `system("cp ./Scripts/x.sh /tmp/")` and start your program with root access (supervisord probably has a way to do that).